# Broken code? Why has it stopped working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-props

When the page loads initially the header should not be visible but when a user begins to scroll the header should appear.

**What do I expect to see?**

The header should not be visible until a user begins to scroll

**What do I see now**

The header is showing when the page first loads and it is not supposed to be showing. **It is only not working as expected in Chrome, and it is working in Safari**.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hide: false
    };
  }

  handleHover = () => {
    this.setState({
      hide: true
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleHover);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleHover);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.hide ? (
          <div
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: "120px",
              margin: "0 auto",
              position: "absolute"
            }}
          >
            <div
              style={{
                zIndex: "0",
                position: "absolute",
                marginLeft: "120px",
                marginTop: "6px"
              }}
            >
              <img className="Logo" src={Logo} alt="logo" />
            </div>
            <div className="menuContainer">
              <nav>
                <Link to="/" className="linkTitle" href="">
                  Home
                </Link>
                <Link to="/shop" className="linkTitle" href="">
                  Shop
                </Link>
                <a className="linkTitle" href="#aboutus">
                  About
                </a>
                <a className="linkTitle" href="">
                  Contact Us
                </a>
                <a className="linkTitle" href="">
                  As seen
                </a>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : null}

        <div className="picContainer">
          <div
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${hairImage})` }}
            className="picSection one"
          />
          <div className="picSection two" />
          <div className="picSection three" />
          <div className="picSection four" />
          <div className="picSectionL five" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow kadddeee! Questions like "why isn't this code working" is not well suited for this forum. Try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrating the issue you are having. Try setting `hide` to `true` in the constructor, and then `hide` to `false` in `handleHover`.

Comment: can you describe what is not working? What do you expect to see?

Comment: Thanks for you're response @leogoesger , the header is showing when the page first loads and its not supposed to be showing. It supposed to console log as false but its on true.

Comment: @Tholle thank you for youre input I have tried to has not worked. hmm and I am looking into the M C V you have mentioned thanks!

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me. https://jsfiddle.net/dL9wk4ot/

Comment: Oh @Chris I have no idea why it wont work for me :( very bizarre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/zlyqyvjzjl

There you go. Make sure you can actually scroll. If you div is too small to scroll, it won't trigger the event.

```
{this.state.hide ? null : <div>some item</div>}
```

Here is the full code:

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hide: true
    };
  }

  handleHover = () => {
    console.log("hello");
    this.setState({
      hide: false
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleHover);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleHover);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: "2000px" }}>
        {this.state.hide ? null : (
          <div
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: "120px",
              margin: "0 auto",
              position: "absolute"
            }}
          >
            <div
              style={{
                zIndex: "0",
                position: "absolute",
                marginLeft: "120px",
                marginTop: "6px"
              }}
            >
              logo
            </div>
          </div>
        )}

        <div className="picContainer">hello</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: I added a height to the first div like yours but it did not help unfortunately. I did switch up my code making this high level div clickable so that on 'onClick' the 'handleHover' function runs and in doing so my code was doing what I wanted it to do . Which tells me my code for doing this when scrolling must be wrong? I don't know help please? I'm fairly new to this :)

Comment: @kadddeee your code is already working, did you check my code? you should just look at mine code, and see what is the difference? Mine is working, and I didn't even change much

Comment: yep I checked you're code I even replicated yours - still not working. When I console log 'this.state.hide' in the console on loading the page it prints a false and also true back to back. :( before it would print just true and on scrolling print false.

Comment: @kadddeee so does it print true when you scroll? But just not appearing?

Comment: yes it prints true when scrolling and on the initial loading of the page it prints both false and true, when it should print just false. Very frustrating I don't get why it prints both, its like it updates to true right after being false on loading.

Comment: so do you see the navbar since it prints `true` now?

Comment: and what browser are you using?

Comment: Yep in the jsfiddle it is was working. I could always see the header thats the issue, on the initial loading of the page I shouldn't be able to see it but I can, hence this post. However as you mentioned a browser I am using chrome I just checked on safari and it is working!!! but I don't know why its not working on chrome :(

Comment: haha, that is weird. It should work for chrome. So for some reason, it is triggering the `scroll` event right after load. I think this could have something to do with other parts of your code or your chrome browser. Maybe close everything, and restart the browser... I know this sounds kind of lame, but since it is working for other browser already

Comment: I can't believe this!!! thank you so much @leogoesger !! I restarted the chrome browser and its working. URGHH so much wasted time. At least now I know what to do when I encounter something similar in the future - oh the joys of coding! Lmao. thanks again

Comment: @kadddeee you should watch IT Crowds, "did you try turn it off and on again?"

Comment: haha I do here a lot about that show but never watch will make sure to watch it soon!